# what exactly does the command brew -v do and how can i undo it?

Tags: homebrew

I am new to using homebrew, and in my naivety i tried the command brew -v to see if that would give me the version of homebrew i have installed, but instead i got this output:

```
==> Downloading https://homebrew.bintray.com/bottles-portable-ruby/portable-ruby-2.3.7.leopard_64.bottle.tar.gz
######################################################################## 100.0%
==> Pouring portable-ruby-2.3.7.leopard_64.bottle.tar.gz
Homebrew 1.7.3-17-g817b72d
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 6b80; last commit 2017-12-22)
```

i am not sure what that just did and where to find it in my system, or how to undo/uninstall whatever i just installed.

Any help would be appreciated

Im on a mac running High Sierra

Comment: Questions about using UNIX tools that aren't specifically about developing software are a better fit for [unix.se] or (for Apple-specific tools like Homebrew) [apple.se]. There's nothing about Brew that's software-development-specific, so it doesn't meet the "unique to software development" criterion ANDed into the other bullet points in https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic.

Comment: ok, thaks for the suggestion, i will take a look at those platforms, stack overflow is justr my usual go-to, it may not be directly soft-dev related, but i am using homebrew for some development purposes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I type `brew -v`, I obtain:

```
Homebrew 1.7.3-2-g654ad46
Homebrew/homebrew-core (git revision 8a091; last commit 2018-09-03)
```

In your case, it first install `portable-ruby` because you never run this command before and homebrew needs this package to run.

This is just a normal behavior.